# backBehavior is not working in react native for current version

Tags: react-native, react-navigation-bottom-tab

react native BackBehavior ="history" or "order" is not working in react native bottom tab for current version what can i do to fix this..suppose from stories if i go to some other page then in their back navigation it should go back to stories tab but i goes to the home tab

```
 <Tab.Navigator navigation={this.props.navigation} backBehavior= "order" >
        <Tab.Screen
          name="home"
          component={MainStackNavigator}
          options={{
            tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => (
              <View>
                <LinearGradient start={{x:0,y: 0}} end= {{x:1,y:0}}>
                  <Image
                    source={require("../../assets/images/home.png")}
                    resizeMode="contain"/>
                </LinearGradient>
                <Text>
                  Home
                </Text>
              </View>
            ),
          }}
        />
        <Tab.Screen
          name="Stories"
          component={Stories} 
          options={{
            tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => (
              <View>
                <LinearGradient start={{x:0,y: 0}} end= {{x:1,y:0}} >
                  <Image
                    source={require("../../assets/images/book.png")}/>
                </LinearGradient>
                <Text
                  style={{
                    color: focused ? "#202877" : "#748c94",
                    fontSize: 12,
                  }}
                >
                  Stories
                </Text>
              </View>
            ),
          }}
        />
</Tab.Navigator>
```

Comment: Create a different stack for the Stories and pass it when you navigate from the that stack you will definitively come previous screen.

Comment: i tried this one but not working @Shivam